# major Difference between rails 3.0 and 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-3.1

What is major Difference between rails 3.0 and 3.1?

I have rails 3.0 app, Should I move to 3.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html), jQuery as the default JavaScript library, Streaming, and Reversible Migrations.